# Can Shamir’s Trick crack the cryptographic strength of ECDSA?

Tags: elliptic-curves, algorithm-design, diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, attack

Recently stumbled upon a discussion in the forum

What is Shamir’s Trick used for?

Are there any such examples?

Comment: You should quote what you are talking about to make your question as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Excuse me ! I edited my post.

Answer (score 6):

No, Shamir's trick doesn't break ECDSA.  Verifying an ECDSA signature involves evaluating a sum of scalar multiplications $[h s^{-1}]G + [r s^{-1}]P$.  You can compute the scalar multiplications $[h s^{-1}]G$ and $[r s^{-1}]P$ separately and then add the results, but Shamir's trick does it more efficiently as a combined computation.

This trick for evaluating a sum of products $[\alpha]P + [\beta]Q$ is to go through the binary expansions of $\alpha = \sum_i \alpha_i 2^i$ and $\beta = \sum_i \beta_i 2^i$ from msb to lsb, and add to the sum either nothing if the bits are both zero, $P$ if only $\alpha_i = 1$, $Q$ if only $\beta_i = 1$, or $P + Q$ if both bits are 1; then double the sum and move on to the next bit.

Beware: If the selection of which point to add or the arithmetic is not done in constant time, this procedure may leak the scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ through timing side channels.  When verifying signatures this is usually not a problem (unless for some reason the signature has to be secret), but other applications may involve a sum of two scalar multiplications whose scalars are secret.

Comment: +1 for the remark that information leakage by side channels matters in signature verification when the signature must be kept secret (e.g. when it signs some low-entropy secret).

Answer (score 1):

Shamir's trick:  Given $N, x, z, e, F$ s.t. $x^e = z^F \mod N$ and $e, F$ are relatively primes, you can efficiently find $z^{1/e}\mod N$. The trick is to compute integers $a,b$ s.t. $a.e + b.F = 1$.

RSA says the following: given $N, y, e$, it's difficult to compute $y^{1/e}\mod N$.

Using shamir's trick you can prove the following: given $N, y, F, e$ s.t. $F,e$ are relatively primes, then it's difficult to compute $y^{F/e}\mod N$.